# Switch between many computers on a projector

Tags: projector, screen-sharing, multiple-computers

I want to project the display from one computer of a set of 4-10 and be able to switch between which is showing the screen on the projector quickly (seconds).

I've been looking at HDMI-switches which is too expensive.

Are there any other possible solutions? Do the online services like 'join.me' work for this scenario?

Comment: Assuming all the target systems are on the same network, have you considered just opening a VNC session to each of them from the system hooked up to the projector and swapping between the individual VNC windows (or tabs if you have a VNC client that uses those)?

Comment: Here to second @AustinHemmelgarn 's idea. Something like TeamViewer would allow you to create a list of PCs you connect to. You could quickly switch between VNC sessions and show remote sessions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned expensive restrictions, rather than purchase hardware you could use a free software solution.

I would suggest using [Veyon](https://veyon.io/) which is designed for teachers to monitor students PCs in a classroom.

In your scenario, the PC connected to the projector is the 'teacher' and can see the monitors of the other PCs (the students) in a grid.
Like this:
[image: Veyon grid]

When you want to view a specific screen you can right click it and view a single PC in full screen.